# Printing HTML String in WKWebView Fails to Print Large PDFs

Tags: swift, wkwebview, uigraphicscontext, uiprintpagerenderer

*Swift 4, Xcode 9.2, iOS 11*

I generate an HTML string that represents a bunch of data displayed in a `WKWebView` like this:

```
//I include this so I can reference some images
let bundle = Bundle.main.bundlePath 

//Load the HTML
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: bundle))
```

Inside my `WKWebView` `didFinish navigation` delegate, I build out the PDF like so:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

  // - 1 - Grab the webView's print context
  let fmt = webView.viewPrintFormatter()

  fmt.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) //Page margins

  // - 2 - Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
  let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
  render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

  // - 3 - Assign paperRect and printableRect
  let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 841.85, height: 595.22) //Page size
  let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

  render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
  render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

  // - 4 - Create PDF context and draw
  let pdfData = NSMutableData()
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, page, nil) //Set page size to landscape

  for i in 0...render.numberOfPages {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
  }

  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

  // - 5 - Save the PDF file
  let pdfURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("PDF")
  let path = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent("MyFile.pdf").path
  pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)

}
```

This works nicely up to ~30 page PDFs. But when I give it a really large web page (40+ pages), then I just get a **blank PDF with a single page** in the end (nothing renders). My suspicion is that the **PDF renderer is crashing or running out of memory**, but there's no indication of that in the logs.

The `htmlString` getting passed in is always complete when I log it. Just the printing fails.

Is there a more efficient or more reliable way to pull this off? Or some way to better troubleshoot what's going on? I'd be so grateful for some help. :)

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I ended up saving each page as a single HTML file to the file system. When it's all done, I grab all the individual files and combine them into a PDF file.